Optimizing Sampling Strategy to Enhance Uniformity Under Conditional Constraints
I am facing a challenge in a project that involves sampling from a design space defined by 10 variables. I use Latin Hypercube Sampling (LHS) and/or Sobol sequences, and initially, the samples are uniformly distributed. The complication arises when I introduce a condition based on a derived variable (DV), which is the product of four of these variables.
Here's the setup:

I sample 10 variables using LHS or Sobol sequences.
I calculate DV from four of these variables.
I retain a sample only if DV falls within a specific range,
discarding others.

This filtering condition aims to ensure that samples meet specific criteria but appears to bias the distribution of DV, affecting sample quality and uniformity. I am considering integrating a resampling strategy that targets regions where DV is underrepresented. The idea is to resample these specific areas more intensively to improve the uniformity of DV across the sampled data.
Questions:

Are there established best practices or modifications to the
sampling process that can maintain a uniform distribution while
adhering to conditional constraints on DV?
Does anyone have experience with or suggestions on using resampling
to enhance data uniformity in the presence of such conditional
constraints?

Any references or pointers on balancing uniform sampling with conditional filtering would be greatly appreciated. This scenario may resonate with many who manage constrained sampling spaces where maintaining a representative and unbiased sample distribution is crucial.
Thank you for any insights or references you can provide!
